# Select columns based on values of another column if present in a list

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I'm trying to select columns A and B from my table in Bigquery using `pandas.read_gbq` based on values of column C if present in a list. However, when I use `format` to insert the list in my query string, the contents of the list are surrounded by `[]` square brackets. This breaks my query.

I used `replace` on the query string to manually remove the square brackets.

```
values_in_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
query = """
SELECT
  column_A,
  column_B

FROM
  my_table

WHERE
 column_C IN ({})
""".format(values_in_list).replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
query_df = pandas.read_gbq(query, project_id='some-project', dialect='standard')
```

This gets the job done. I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution than brute forcing it.

Comment: It is better to pass `values_in_list` through query parameters, see this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/31a13933d6adcbd775bfa28e85ced62f058cf9c9/bigquery/pandas-gbq-migration/samples_test.py#L141).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I followed the link you provided. When I use `'type': 'STRING'` `paramterType` this query returns only the values like the first element of the list. When I tried `'type': 'ARRAY'`, it returned a `BadRequest` based on `GenericGBQException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if `pandas.read_gbq` supports `ArrayQueryParameters` in the `query_config` keyword arg. Here's my workaround:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

values_in_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
query = """
SELECT
  column_A,
  column_B

FROM
  my_table

WHERE
 column_C IN UNNEST(@col_c_vals)
"""

query_params = [bigquery.ArrayQueryParameter('col_c_vals', 'STRING', values_in_list)]
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.query_parameters = query_params
query_df = client.query(query, job_config=job_config).to_dataframe()
```